# Is there a way of showing Salesforce a bunch of codes and it telling me how many exist already?

Tags: appexchange, app, upload, insert, product

Basically I upload products into SF every week - we have had an issue with our product tool and basically may need to load in thousands that are missing.

We identify every product with a 'module code' (e.g. GDGE0758CAR) - Is there an app or a method of being able to show SalesForce hundreds / thousands of these codes and it tell me how many of them exist already? Possibly an app or anything really.

Kind regards
Paul

Comment: Is the field external id? You can certainly run a data load.

Comment: It's a custom field named "Module Code" it's not the only field that identifies it as the specific product but it's the most relevant. I know I can extract and then de-dupe but we have over 3million products so it would be much easier if I could import and be told that it already exists or use a tool that matches the codes up with existing codes already live.

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. If it is external and you do want to create the missing data, textbook case for `upsert`.

Comment: sorry mate - I don't think I understood it. It's an external ID as in we/the company generate it. So if we upsert it will look for anything in there and insert anything that isnt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For text fields, there is a configuration option to use it as an external id.

> ## [Upserting Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm)
>
> Using the `upsert` operation, you can either insert or update an existing record in one call. To determine whether a record already exists, the `upsert` statement or Database method uses the record’s ID as the key to match records, a custom external ID field, or a standard field with the `idLookup` attribute set to true.
>
> - If the key is not matched, then a new object record is created.
> - If the key is matched once, then the existing object record is updated.
> - If the key is matched multiple times, then an error is generated and the object record is neither inserted or updated.